Netplan: How to route an ip to a device and how to set a source ip for a default route?
I am configuring a multi-internet-ip network on a root server with many vms.
My network is fully functional now (to the intended extend) but I had to set up some routes manually without netplan.
Can you help me to translate these rules to netplan syntax?
How to route an ip to a device with netplan?
ip route add 89.199.52.217/32 dev  br0_opnsense

I found this questions here: Add a device static route with netplan
Do I just have to configure my route on br0_opnsense and write scope: link? Will try this now.
How to set a source ip for a route with netplan?
ip route add default via 192.168.69.2 src 89.199.52.217 dev ens1

I tried to add a src: parameter to my routes as suggested by chat gpt but it just produced a syntax error.
I hope you can help me to translate these ip route commands to the netplan syntax.
